# How to measure latency using wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark, tcpdump, latency

I'm trying to measure the wire-to-wire latency of a blackbox application. The application engages in tcp offloading (kernel bypass), it consumes incoming UDP packets via a NIC and in response, publishes outgoing TCP packets via the same NIC. What applications can I use for this purpose? Two versions of the applications are run - one on Windows server and another on Linux

It would be similar to this result - http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2015/08/tick-to-trade-latency-numbers-using-coralfix-and-coralreactor/

The problem with the above methodology seems to be that since our application is bypassing the kernel, we need to record the timestamps of the incoming and outgoing packets from the NIC itself (wireshark uses the timestamp once the packets reach the kernel (https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvTimestamps.html)

ANy ideas? Also please correct me if I'm wrong - I'm a complete networking noob